# Axioms for structures with one binary operation?

Tags: abstract-algebra, axioms

In my (limited) experience of algebra, I have only seen a handful of axioms used.
The wikipedia page on [outline of algebraic structures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outline_of_algebraic_structures) lists a table of the following axioms for structures with one binary operation. The only axiom that I can think of that's missing is **idempotency**.

[image]

I personally find it surprising if there are so few natural axioms for binary operators (6 basically). **Are there other axioms on binary operators that are used? Perhaps in much more niche contexts? I would be interested to see a larger list of axioms and to know in what contexts they would be used.**

Answer (score 0):

Well, the lattice as algebraic structure is based on the axioms of associativity, commutativity, and the absorption laws.
Idempotency is then a derived law.